# Enable Breadcrumb in oslo master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, dashboard-designer-2013, office-365-develop-tool

I required to Enable the breadcrumb in Oslo master page  and I am following the url http://www.wombit.se/2013/11/28/sharepoint-365-breadcrumb-oslo/ which is showing to add the snippet of code, But in URL it is not mentioned under which tag should I add the code. 
          Can any one help me in which exact tag of master.Page should I add the code and get back the breadcrumb in Oslo.master

Comment: why don't you ask the author of the blog post? There's a section for comments. Or, since the code is copied from the Seattle master, find where it lives in Seattle.master and stick it in the same position in a copy of Oslo.master (never edit the original master).

Comment: Hi :) We all knew they doesn't respond .I too tried on getting this info. But I don't find any result. Hope you look further to help

Comment: To add to teylyn's comment, you should not even be editing the .masters, but the .htmls that are partnered with them.

Answer (score 1):

In the seattle master, that div lies within the `ms-breadcrumb-top` div, which is within the `ms-breadcrumb-box` div.  I can see the latter in the oslo master.
Starting with the `s4-workspace` div:

```
<div id="s4-workspace" class="ms-core-overlay">
        <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
            <div id="s4-titlerow" class="ms-dialogHidden s4-titlerowhidetitle">
                <div id="titleAreaBox" class="ms-noList ms-table ms-core-tableNoSpace">
                    <div id="titleAreaRow" class="ms-tableRow">
                        <div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ms-breadcrumb-box ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
                            <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
                                <div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox">
```